# tic tac toe horizontal/vertical and diagonal check not wokring - java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a tic tac toe game and everything seems to work except the checks (horizontal/vertical and diagonal). I am using an array (`int [3][3]`) to make the board.

These are my checks:

```
private boolean wonStraightLines( int player)
   {
       boolean answer = false;

       if (
            ((board[0][0] & board[0][1] & board[0][2]) == (player * 3)) || 
            ((board[1][0] & board[1][1] & board[1][2]) == (player * 3)) ||  
            ((board[2][0] & board[2][1] & board[2][2]) == (player * 3)) ||
            ((board[0][0] & board[1][0] & board[2][0]) == (player * 3)) ||
            ((board[0][1] & board[1][1] & board[2][1]) == (player * 3)) ||
            ((board[0][2] & board[1][2] & board[2][2]) == (player * 3))
          ) 
       {
           answer = true;   
       }
       else {
           answer = false;
       }
       return answer;
   }
```

and for the diagonal:

```
private boolean wonDiagonal( int player)
   {
      boolean answer = false;

      if (
              ((board[0][0] & board[1][1] & board[2][2]) == (player * 3)) || ((board[0][2] & board[1][1] & board[2][0]) == (player * 3))
         ) 
      {
          answer = true;
      }
      else {
          answer = false;
      }
      return answer;
   }
```

when I run the program whenever X or O get 3 from any direction the game keeps running rather than throwing out a "you win" message. Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if any other parts of the code are needed or not.

EDIT: I also tried using the + instead of the & between the board array values but did not work as well.

Comment: Are you sure your `wonStraightLines` is working properly?

Comment: What values are you keeping in board? 0,1 or 2 maybe? Even can't assume now. What are the possible variables of `player`? Changing the `&` to `+` is HUUUGE logic change... I think you'd rather use `&&` logical and not `&` bitwise operator. With `&&` you need to compare each operand to `player*3`

Comment: And why are you using bitwise operator (`&`)? I'm assuming that you are aware of the `and/&` bitwise operator returns the value based on bit to bit copy of each operand, making the bit as 1 only if every operand had 1 in that bit, otherwise 0. Bitwise expression is evaluated to int and you compare it with `player*3`. I'm not gonna go with possibilities of this, because I think you'd wanted to use logical `&&` instead of `&` bitwise. There is no easy shorthand in Java for comparing multiple variables with a single other one. It must go as `a==X && b==X && c==X`.

Comment: That is the issue @user7 both of them are NOT working, that's what my problem is, I tried using the & and + but neither work

Comment: @itwasntme I don't think I am keeping any values on board, the variable for player is a player (defined as int) I tried using && but apparently did not work for the integer and array types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming there are 3 unique values for the states of each element such as for example:

```
board[row][col] = 0 // no entry
board[row][col] = 1 // player 1
board[row][col] = 2 // player 2
```

Without being clever a horizontal check for `player` (using row-major structure) would look like:

```
(board[0][0] == player && board[0][1] == player && board[0][2] == player)
```

and repeat for each row.

And similar for vertical, repeating for each column:

```
(board[0][0] == player && board[1][0] == player && board[2][0] == player)
```

And one diagonal:

```
(board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player)
```

If you were determined to use an arithmetic operation then you'd have to change the "player" values to avoid overlap, as in player 1 == 1 and player 2 == 4, such as:

```
board[row][col] = 0 // no entry
board[row][col] = 1 // player 1
board[row][col] = 4 // player 2
```

Then you could do something like for a horizontal row:

```
((board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]) == (player * 3))
```

Note in Java 8 and later adding an int array (a row or column in your case) can be slightly more succinct:

```
// sum the first row
(IntStream.of(board[0]).sum() == (player * 3))
```

Now if you really wanted to use the bit-wise "and" operation then this is your check assuming the initial element values (0,1,2) as stated at top:

```
// check if the player's "bit" is set in all elements of first row.
(board[0][0] & board[0][1] & board[0][2]) == player
```

Comment: Looks ok, I'm just in the side of requiring some1 to do more research or simply, to ask more adequate question (or at least with more details). Maybe the bitwise operations are needed here (regardless the reason of using them), there's a possibility to keep the equasions with them, but all other used values are needed (and possible changing of the `0` to something bigger to avoid wrong results). Regardless, yours looks good, a small explanation between & and && would be good. There are (prbbly) standard API methods for transmutation of matrices, so IntStream, could be used wth diagonal.